# Python - How to send message with Viber bot?

Tags: python, viber, viber-api, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

I want to create some sort of Viber bot to send messages to Viber user, actually just to notify them.

I've tried to follow their [documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/python-bot-api/), but I couldn't make it work, because it was not clear to me at all. So, can you guys provide me some guide how can I send message to Viber user using Python?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [working sample](https://github.com/Viber/viber-bot-python/blob/master/sample_bot.py) from Viber company, written with [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) and [viber-bot-python](https://github.com/Viber/viber-bot-python) library.